DeserializeJSON works within CFDUMP, but fails when using it to set a variable
It's very strange, but I'm trying to set a variable which fails:
<cfset ResultsArray = DeserializeJSON(ResultsJSON.filecontent)>

However, if I use CFDUMP right above it, it works:
<cfdump var="#DeserializeJSON(ResultsJSON.filecontent)#">

The value ResultsJSON.filecontent is valid, according to IsJson(ResultsJSON.filecontent). The result is about 45K, so nothing huge.
Is there something I am missing about the use of cfdump vs setting a variable in ColdFusion 2021?
Here's more weirdness:
<cfset isItJson = isjson( ResultsJSON.filecontent)> 
<cfdump var="#isItJson#"><br><br> 
<cfdump var="#isjson( ResultsJSON.filecontent)#"><br><br> 
<cfdump var="#ResultsJSON.filecontent#"><br><br> 
<cfdump var="#DeserializeJSON(ResultsJSON.filecontent)#"> 
<cfabort> 

this works and results in
YES 
YES 
the JSON content 
the JSON as an array of structs 

if i remove the <cfabort>, i get the error on the line with <cfdump var="#DeserializeJSON(ResultsJSON.filecontent)#">.
srsly, what is going on?

How does it fail? Is there an error message? If so, what does it say?

Oops, that would help, huh? The error is:  JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string

What's in the actual string? Maybe there's a non-printing character or something that's causing the error, but somehow cfdump knows how to handle it?

Here's a small sample, its very simple data:
[{"meetingDate":"April 15, 2024","agendaId":16589},{"meetingDate":"April 15, 2024","agendaId":16609},{"meetingDate":"April 8, 2024","agendaId":16569},{"meetingDate":"April 1, 2024","agendaId":16550},{"meetingDate":"March 18, 2024","agendaId":16549},{"meetingDate":"February 14, 2024","agendaId":16529}]

What's even stranger is if I copy-paste the raw data to a variable named sampleData in the CF code and use  , it works...

There is no reason why this wouldn't work. You need to update your question with more details. Show the dump of the content before deserialize and what cfdump shows etc. It will be something to do with the data being received.

Do some bog-standard debugging... put a try/catch around the erroring code and check the value it's trying to deserialize. My initial thoughts are that this code is in a method of a CFC instances that's being run by multiple threads at a time, and ResultsJSON is being changed by a different thread between the two statements. What scope is ResultsJSON in?

The full string of data is just more of the same from the sample i pasted. Just simple string representations of meetingDate and ints for agendaId.  ResultsJSON is in the variables scope.

And there's nothing fishy at the end of the JSON? Considering Unexpected end of JSON string...

nope, it ends with ], as expected. Even used several JSON lint'ers. Here's more weirdness:
<cfset isItJson = isjson( ResultsJSON.filecontent)>





this works and results in
YES
YES
the JSON content
the JSON as an array of structs
if i remove the , i get the error on the line with .
srsly, what is going on?

See my earlier comment. You ain't done that yet.

Try doing an cfoutput and setting a Javascript variable. See if your browser and parse it.

Please post the full file content that is being retrieved as JSON into your post above. With "full" I mean showing not just the data, but also any white spaces and new lines coming from there.
